# How to download a secured file using curl from s3 bucket using SecretAccessKey and AccessKeyId

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to download an apk which exists into my private s3 bucket using curl command. I dont want to use awscli/boto3. I have SecretAccessKey, SessionToken, Expiration, AccessKeyId

Tried Following Code:

```
curl -k -v -L -o url="https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com" -H "x-amz-security-token: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" -H "Content-Type: application/xml" -X GET https://xyz/test.apk


curl -k -v -L -o url="https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com" -H "Content-Type: application/xml" -X GET https://xyz/.test.apk?AWSAccessKeyId=xxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Comment: did you tried my answer?

Comment: Yes. Just tried and it worked. Thanks :)

Comment: Yes, you can run this from any system by passing the argument. you can check this https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/simple-fun-dynamic-ssh-adil-m/ and also you can pass this command to ssh

Comment: @Adiii so i have created the curl command using your file. If i want to use the curl command to be fired from different machine, is it possible? i am a noob in shell script. Actually openssl is not available on the machine from which i want to fire the curl command. Thanks in advance.

Comment: To just make sure we are on the same page, my main machine doesnt have openssl, so i will create a curl command from different machine and use it to be fired from main machine on which openssl is not there.
Currently by doing so, it is giving me 400 Bad Request.

Comment: @Adiii is there a way to do so??

Comment: Opensll is mandatory, the other way can be aws-cli  or docker to download the file from s3 using curl and terminate the container after download.

Comment: or if you know md5 of a file that might be possible so you do not need to generate one

Comment: Thanks buddy much appreciated. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the script that downloads and upload file to s3, you have to export keys or can modify the script accordingly.

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=AKxxx
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=zzzz
```

## Download a file

```
./s3download.sh get s3://mybucket/myfile.txt myfile.txt
```

That's it, all you need to pass s3 bucket along with file name

```
    #!/bin/bash
set -eu
s3simple() {
  local command="$1"
  local url="$2"
  local file="${3:--}"

  # todo: nice error message if unsupported command?

  if [ "${url:0:5}" != "s3://" ]; then
    echo "Need an s3 url"
    return 1
  fi
  local path="${url:4}"

  if [ -z "${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID-}"  ]; then
    echo "Need AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID to be set"
    return 1
  fi

  if [ -z "${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY-}" ]; then
    echo "Need AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY to be set"
    return 1
  fi

  local method md5 args
  case "$command" in
  get)
    method="GET"
    md5=""
    args="-o $file"
    ;;
  put)
    method="PUT"
    if [ ! -f "$file" ]; then
      echo "file not found"
      exit 1
    fi
    md5="$(openssl md5 -binary $file | openssl base64)"
    args="-T $file -H Content-MD5:$md5"
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Unsupported command"
    return 1
  esac

  local date="$(date -u '+%a, %e %b %Y %H:%M:%S +0000')"
  local string_to_sign
  printf -v string_to_sign "%s\n%s\n\n%s\n%s" "$method" "$md5" "$date" "$path"
  local signature=$(echo -n "$string_to_sign" | openssl sha1 -binary -hmac "${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}" | openssl base64)
  local authorization="AWS ${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}:${signature}"

  curl $args -s -f -H Date:"${date}" -H Authorization:"${authorization}" https://s3.amazonaws.com"${path}"
}

s3simple "$@"
```

You can find more detail [here](https://github.com/paulhammond/s3simple)